# Property [referred_by] does not exist on this collection instance.Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

```
public function upgrade()
{
$captain = DB::table('users')->where('referral_id',Auth::user()->referred_by)->get();
    $captain2gen = DB::table('users')->where('referral_id',$captain-
>referred_by)->first();
    return view('upgrade', ['captain' => $captain, 'captain2gen' => 
$captain2gen]);
}
```

this is my controller for a project am doing. Am not showing my view cos i know the problem is from the $captain2gen line of code. Anyone has an idea on how i could rewrite this code better? Thanks in advance!

Comment: how about `$captain2gen = DB::table('users')->where('referral_id',$captain-
>referred_id)->first();`? because it says refferd_by does not exist

Comment: you can use users table both time and why not use single time ?

Comment: Hi Patrick! It looks like [you recently tried to suggest an edit to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16983857) using another account. It got rejected by the community because it looked like someone else abusing the suggested edit feature to try and put words in your mouth. But since the user names were the same, I just wanted to check and see if maybe you accidentally created 2 accounts and couldn't figure out how to merge them together so you'd be in control of your question. If that's the case, please respond to me here or raise a flag; we can help you out.